# Exchange 2010 OWA Dictionary

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-web-app, spellcheck

My company has just started using OWA to allow staff to send emails while on the road. Company policy is to have auto spell check turned on however we want to be able to add words to the dictionary (for example the company name).

From what I can tell there isn't a way to do this in exchange (e.g. [this from technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchange2010/thread/2d1da8af-5fb9-4a81-8058-38121ac25805/))

Are there any third party tools or work arounds to add words to the dictionary?